# R, python or octave: empirical quantile (inverse cdf) with confidence intervals?

Tags: c#, python, r, statistics, octave

I'm looking for a built-in function that returns the sample quantile **and an estimated confidence interval** in something other than MATLAB (MATLAB's `ecdf` does this).

I'm guessing R has this built-in and I just haven't found it yet.

If you have any standalone code to do this, you could also point to it here, though I hope to find something that is included as part of a larger open code base.

-Trying to get away from MATLAB.

Comment: Well googling 'r ecdf' shows that there is an ecdf function in the stats package, but it might not have confidence intervals. Not sure how you would expect intervals on a cumulative distribution function anyway. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The cdf is *estimated* from a set of samples. As the number of independent samples grows, you generally expect the uncertainty to decrease. 

What I'm currently doing is using matlab's ecdf which return an estimate of the cdf as well as an estimate of the lower and upper bound for this estimate. So you have three "curves", the estimated cdf and the upper and lower curve. I then invert the cdfs and their bounds after a linear interpolation of each.

This is probably not consistent with doing something like a bootstrap estimate for the confidence interval on a quantile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `survfit` function can be used to get the *survival* function with confidence intervals. Since it is just 1-ecdf, there is a direct relationship between the quantiles. To use this you have to create a variable that says that each of your observations is complete (not censored):

```
library(survival)
x <- rexp(10)
ev <- rep(1, length(x))
sf <- survfit(Surv(x,ev)~1)
```

With output:

```
>summary(sf)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(x, ev) ~ 1)

     time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
-1.4143     10       1      0.9  0.0949       0.7320        1.000
-1.1229      9       1      0.8  0.1265       0.5868        1.000
-0.9396      8       1      0.7  0.1449       0.4665        1.000
-0.4413      7       1      0.6  0.1549       0.3617        0.995
-0.2408      6       1      0.5  0.1581       0.2690        0.929
-0.1698      5       1      0.4  0.1549       0.1872        0.855
 0.0613      4       1      0.3  0.1449       0.1164        0.773
 0.1983      3       1      0.2  0.1265       0.0579        0.691
 0.5199      2       1      0.1  0.0949       0.0156        0.642
 0.8067      1       1      0.0     NaN           NA           NA
```

In fact, `survfit` does calculate the median and its confidence interval, but not the other quantiles:

```
>sf
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(x, ev) ~ 1)

records   n.max n.start  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
 10.000  10.000  10.000  10.000  -0.205  -0.940      NA
```

The actual work for of the calculation of the confidence interval of the median is well hidden in the `survival:::survmean` function, which you could probably use to generalize to other quantiles.

Comment: Interesting, not an entirely obvious place to look. Thanks!