# How do you plot a CDF and a ECDF inkl. band?

Tags: r

It's simple to plot an empirical cumulative function. But I would love to see a confidence band around it.

```
x = rnorm(100, 250, 1)
ex = ecdf(x)
plot(ex)
```

(Currenty, i don't care about the size of the band). I simply want to understand how to plot the band in R. Anyone any clue?

Objective: At the end, I want an ECDF and its band. An additional CDF should be printed to demonstrate, that it's within the band. So similar like the link below, but with an band around the ECDF. This is for the graphical "proof". For the numerik proof I compute the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Goodness-Of-Fit Test.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Empirical_CDF.png

Comment: How would you calculate the confidence band mathematically? (I don't think there is something like that for `ecdf`.) If your question is only about plotting: Use ggplot2 and `geom_ribbon`.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed. I post an example to this thread later.

Comment: This shows how to compute the intervals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442810/r-python-or-octave-empirical-quantile-inverse-cdf-with-confidence-intervals